# What does $(\text{Second Moment})^3+(\text{Third Moment})^2$ equal?

Tags: statistics

I have an equation as follows

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{1}
\left(-\frac{\mu_2(\alpha)}{2}\right)^3+
\left(\frac{\mu_3(\alpha)}{2}\right)^2
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
where $\mu_2(\alpha)$ is the second central moment of a set of variables $\alpha$ and $\mu_3(\alpha)$ is the third central moment of the same set of variables. (This equation actually lives under a square root, but that may be irrelevant...)

I'm wondering if this is itself a statistic function?

I've tried relating it to the sixth central moment and kurtosis, but with no luck as yet.

Comment: The expression is related to $\beta_1(\alpha)$ (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution)), namely $\left(-\frac{\mu_2(\alpha)}{2}\right)^3+
\left(\frac{\mu_3(\alpha)}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{8} \mu_2^3(\alpha) \left(\beta_1 - 1 \right)$. Parameter $\beta_1$ is the square of the skewness parameter, i.e. $\beta_1 = \gamma_1^2$. The parameter can not be expressed though higher moments(i.e. 6-th and 4-th as you tried, unless some specific distribution is being considered).

Comment: "Equation" is the wrong word here.  The word "equation" has a particular meaning.  Look it up.

Comment: @Sasha It seems that your comment indeed answered the question, and should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is related to $\beta_1(\alpha)$ (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution)), namely $$
\left(-\frac{\mu_2(\alpha)}{2}\right)^3+
\left(\frac{\mu_3(\alpha)}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{8} \mu_2^3(\alpha) \left(\beta_1 - 1 \right)$$

Parameter $\beta_1$ is the square of the skewness parameter, i.e. $\beta_1 = \gamma_1^2$. The parameter can not be expressed through higher moments (i.e. 6-th and 4-th as you tried, unless some specific distribution is being considered).